# How to Use Amazon AWS Credentials to Access/Query Tables in AWS RDS Instance through Mobile App

Tags: c#, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, credentials

I've been quite confused for a couple of weeks.  Did a ton of research on how to actually connect to an AWS RDS SQL Server Instance through my mobile app and no cigar.

At this point, I can do the following:
I can connect to it using SQL Management Server Client with no problem.  I am using AUTH0 to get the AWS Credentials, Session Token, Secret Access Key, ARN of the assumed role, etc...

How do I use the AWS credentials to access and query an RDS Database Instance?  I know I have to use some kind of HTTP/REST to request information but how?  In what format?  Can you give me an example?  Do I need to use EC2 to access it?  I am so confused, but I think at this point I am really close, so please help.  I am currently using C# (XAMARIN) to code my Android App.

Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 1):

> I know I have to use some kind of HTTP/REST to request information but
>   how? In what format?

There is no HTTP/REST endpoint available out of the box. That's something you would have to build yourself and run on an EC2 server or maybe on Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your backend functions to do this. I use Node.js and the 'serverless' framework, which can be downloaded through npm. You can execute SQL commands through the node.js code. Then upload the function to AWS Lambda. Finally you make an endpoint via API Gateway and you can download their pre-generated sdk to access your functions through your client (the mobile app). Check out this channel, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSUEk6iMW88